# Colocar um hífen quando o valor for 0 no select

Tags: mysql, sql, query

Como posso fazer no `mysql` uma `query` (SELECT) para que quando o valor for igual a `0`, substitua-o por `hífen(-)`.

Campo do valor: int.

Comment: Um update? Qual o tipo da coluna?

Comment: Qual é o tipo de campo? varchar?

Comment: Um `SELECT` o campo é do tipo `int`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Eduardo Santos,

Caso você queira trocar o 0 pelo hífen em um select você faz assim:

```
SELECT IF(seu_campo = 0, '-', seu_campo) AS nome_para_esse_resultado FROM sua_tabela;
```

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar um [`IF`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) na consulta.

O `IF` recebe três "parâmetros", o primeiro é a condição, o segundo é o valor que a coluna assumirá caso a condição seja atendida e o terceiro é o valor que a coluna vai assumir caso contrário.

```
Select If(Campo = 0, '-', Campo) From Tabela
```

[Documentação do IF](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if)

Answer (score 1):

```
Select IIF(Campo = 0, '-', campo) AS CAMPOSELECIONADO from TABELA
```

Isso funcionaria para o seu caso.